How in getEloquentQuery to check which status filter is selected now?
In laravel 10 / filamentphp 3 app I have a table with default ordering and several filters :
public static function getEloquentQuery(): Builder
{
    return parent::getEloquentQuery()->with('quizCategory')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->orderBy('status', 'asc');
}

public static function table(Table $table): Table
    {
        $getOrderingFormat = app(GetOrderingFormatInterface::class);
        $orderQuizCategoryByName = $getOrderingFormat->get('name');

        return $table
            ->columns([
                TextColumn::make('id')->sortable(),
                TextColumn::make('quizCategory.name')->sortable()->searchable()->hiddenOn(UserQuizRequestsRelationManager::class),

                TextColumn::make('summary_points_percent')
                    ->getStateUsing(function (Model $record): string {
                        return UserQuizRequestHelper::getSummaryPointsPercent($record);
                    }),
                TextColumn::make('user_name')->sortable()->searchable(),
                EmailColumn::make('user_email')->sortable()->searchable(),
                TextColumn::make('status')->badge()->sortable()->searchable(),
                TextColumn::make('expires_at')
                    ->formatStateUsing(fn(string $state): string => DateConv::getFormattedDateTime($state)),
                TextColumn::make('created_at')
                    ->formatStateUsing(fn(string $state): string => DateConv::getFormattedDateTime($state))
                    ->toggleable(isToggledHiddenByDefault: true),
            ])
            ->striped()
            ->filters([
                Filter::make('filter_user_quiz_request_status_waiting_for_employee_quiz_result')->label('Waiting for job seeker quiz result')
                    ->query(fn(Builder $query): Builder => $query->where('status',
                        UserQuizRequestStatus::WAITING_FOR_JOB_SEEKER_QUIZ_RESULT))
                    ->indicator('Waiting for job seeker quiz needs for managers review'),
                Filter::make('filter_user_quiz_request_status_needs_for_managers_review')->label('Needs for managers review')
                    ->query(fn(Builder $query): Builder => $query->where('status',
                        UserQuizRequestStatus::NEEDS_FOR_MANAGERS_REVIEW))
                    ->indicator('Needs for managers review'),
                Filter::make('filter_user_quiz_request_status_accept_for_meeting')->label('Accept for meeting')
                    ->query(fn(Builder $query): Builder => $query->where('status',
                        UserQuizRequestStatus::ACCEPT_FOR_MEETING))
                    ->indicator('Accept for meeting'),
                Filter::make('filter_user_quiz_request_status_hired_and_saved_as_employee')->label('Hired and saved as employee')
                    ->query(fn(Builder $query): Builder => $query->where('status',
                        UserQuizRequestStatus::HIRED))
                    ->indicator('Hired and saved as employee'),
                Filter::make('filter_user_quiz_request_status_mark_for_future_contacts')->label('Marked for future contacts')
                    ->query(fn(Builder $query): Builder => $query->where('status',
                        UserQuizRequestStatus::MARK_FOR_FUTURE_CONTACTS))
                    ->indicator('Marked for future contacts'),
                Filter::make('filter_user_quiz_request_status_expired')->label('Expired')
                    ->query(fn(Builder $query): Builder => $query->where('status', UserQuizRequestStatus::EXPIRED))
                    ->indicator('Expired'),
                Filter::make('filter_user_quiz_request_status_rejected')->label('Rejected')
                    ->query(fn(Builder $query): Builder => $query->where('status', UserQuizRequestStatus::REJECTED))
                    ->indicator('Rejected'),

                SelectFilter::make('quiz_category_id')->label('Quiz category')
                    ->options(QuizCategory::query()->orderByRaw($orderQuizCategoryByName)->pluck('name', 'id'))
                    ->multiple()
                    ->searchable()
                    ->preload()
                    ->indicator('Quiz category selected')
                    ->hiddenOn(UserQuizRequestsRelationManager::class),
            ])
            ->actions([
                Tables\Actions\ViewAction::make()->iconButton(),
                Tables\Actions\EditAction::make()->iconButton(), //->visible(UserQuizRequestsRelationManager::class),
                Tables\Actions\DeleteAction::make()->iconButton()
                    ->successNotificationTitle('User quiz request successfully deleted')
            ], position: ActionsPosition::BeforeColumns)
            ->bulkActions([
                Tables\Actions\BulkActionGroup::make([
                    Tables\Actions\DeleteBulkAction::make(),
                ]),
            ]);

    }

my table looks like :

It has grouping by status. I remember I used some method for that grouping, but can not find now which. a) Please, remind.
b) If some group/status selected I need to change order of data. In other words how in getEloquentQuery to check which status filter is selected now ?
Replies:
